# how to get 10 -10 contacts from contact in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

here in my app i need to fetch only 10 contacts and next 10 contacts will fetch when I press next button and so on..

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        i = 0;
        count = 0;
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);

        names = new String[cur.getCount()];
        phone = new String[cur.getCount()];

        if ((cur.getCount() > 0)) {

            if (count < 5) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cur
                            .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    if (Integer
                            .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                        Cursor pCur = cr
                                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                + " = ?",
                                        new String[] { id }, null);

                        while (pCur.moveToNext() && i < 5) {
                            String phoneNo = pCur
                                    .getString(pCur
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                            names[i] = name;
                            phone[i] = phoneNo;
                            if (i == 0)
                                fulldata += "\"" + i + "\"" + ":" + "{"
                                        + "\"" + "phone" + "\"" + ":"
                                        + "\"" + phoneNo + "\"" + "}";
                            else
                                fulldata += "," + "\"" + i + "\"" + ":"
                                        + "{" + "\"" + "phone" + "\"" + ":"
                                        + "\"" + phoneNo + "\"" + "}";
                            i++;
                        }
                        pCur.close();
                    }

                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // {_action:addcontacts,contacts:{"0":{"phone":"8098098"},"1":{"phone":"8098090"},"2":{"phone":"8096879"}}}
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        fulldata += "}";
        Log.i("all data to post", "" + fulldata);
        new UpdateContacts().execute();
    }
}
```

I am getting all contacts from this code block but i need to fetch specific(10) number of contact in list and when I click on next button that time it should fetch next (10 numbers)list of number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for LIMIT function.

`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10` --> get 1st 10 records

`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10, 10` --> get 10 records after row 10

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, "LIMIT 10, " + count);
count += 10;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is to add the LIMIT and OFFSET qualifiers to your query.  Example:

```
select * from MyTable where <whatever> limit 10 offset 30;
```

This would get rows 30 - 39.

Whether you can make this work through the cr.query() call, I don't know.