# Setting a limit of 200 numbers when loading from the contacts

Tags: android, limit, contacts

i want to set the limit per 200 unit when load all contact number,in my current code is load all contact number in one time, here is my code, where i should put the function / condition for limit per 200 ? 
here is my current code :

```
 private void loadContact() {
    ContentResolver cr = applicationContext.getContentResolver();
    String[] PROJECTION = ContactsQuery.PROJECTION;

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            PROJECTION,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String lookUpKey = cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.LOOKUP_KEY);
        loadContactDetail(lookUpKey);
    }
    cursor.close();
}

private void loadContactDetail(String lookUpKey) {
    ContentResolver cr = applicationContext.getContentResolver();

    String[] COLS = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, COLS,
            ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY + " = ?",
            new String[]{lookUpKey},
            null
    );

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        String formatted = Util.formatMSISDN(phone);
        if (formatted !=null) {
            contactsSet.add(formatted);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: what is contactsSet if its a List u can put condition if(contactsSet.size()==200) or u can see this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501375/how-to-get-10-10-contacts-from-contact-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You can have a query like the following:

`cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, //Table
            PROJECTION, //Projection
            null, //Selection
            null, //Selection Args
            null, //Group By
            null, //Having
            null, //Order By
            " LIMIT 200" //Limit
    );`

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
 int count = 0;

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        if (count == 200) break;

        String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        String formatted = Util.formatMSISDN(phone);
        if (formatted !=null) {
            contactsSet.add(formatted);
        }

        count++;
    }
```

and look towards the method`boolean move (int offset);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            PROJECTION,
            null,
            null,
             " LIMIT 200"
    );
  while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
   //get data here 
}
```